# Javascript draw on multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to draw the same thing on multiple canvases gotten by class selector. What am I doing wrong?

```
var canvases = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas');

for( var i=0; i<canvases.length; i++){
   ctx = canvases[i].getContext('2d');

   ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 1.5*Math.PI);
   ctx.lineWidth = 15;

   ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
   ctx.stroke();    
}
```

Her's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6Knc/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare them as `<canvas>` elements, not `<div>` elements.  Canvases are their own specific HTML5 element.

Accordingly can also get rid of the class and use `getElementsByTagName` instead of `getElementsByClassName` with a few minor CSS and markup changes:

**HTML**

```
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
```

**CSS**

```
canvas {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**JS**

```
var canvases = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');

for( var i=0; i<canvases.length; i++){
     ctx = canvases[i].getContext('2d');

     ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 1.5*Math.PI);
     ctx.lineWidth = 15;

     ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
     ctx.stroke();    
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6Knc/2/)