# Can I use same canvas id to position same graphics in two different position?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to use the same canvas id for identical drawings, but trying to put them in different positions. It's only letting me position the first graphic.

```js
var display = new drawDisplay("display");
display.pattern = "#";
display.cornerType = 2;
display.displayType = 7;
display.displayAngle = 0;
display.digitHeight = 32;
display.digitWidth = 20;
display.digitDistance = 2;
display.segmentWidth = 3;
display.segmentDistance = 0.5;
display.colorOn = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)";
display.colorOff = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";

draw();

function draw() {
  display.setValue();
  window.setTimeout('draw()', 100);
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 1796px; height: 184px; position: relative">
  <img src="A24.jpg" usemap="#indbuttonmap">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 121px; top: 17px; width: 35px; height: 57px">
    <canvas id="display" width="35" height="57"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 119px; top: 115px; width: 35px; height: 57px">
    <canvas id="display" width="35" height="57"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to do exactly/expected output? Can you also share the code of `drawDisplay` and what it does.

Comment: Not possible. You've to create different ids and store the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` object of the canvases to a variable.

Comment: I am trying to draw a 7segment on an image but in multiple positions of the image. The canvas position is relative to that image. 

drawDisplay () will do the drawing, for the seven segement. For the first canvas, it successfully draws. If i create two different ids for the canvas, and create tow objects for the drawDisplay() based on that id, it works as well. But, I would like to keep the same drawing and just position it in multiple places over my image.

Comment: You cannot use the same ID in multiple HTML elements... an ID **must** be unique

Comment: > Can I use same canvas id to position same graphics in two different position? No.

Comment: See [Javascript draw on multiple canvases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014276/javascript-draw-on-multiple-canvases)